# Is there a proof show that : $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ are images of unbounded functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

if we knew that :cos and sin are bounded function $\mathbb{R}$ for any real

number $x$ .

let $z $ be a complex variable , Is there a proof show that :

$\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$ are images of  unbounded functions ?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: non constant + entire implies unbounded (Liouville)

Comment: ok, how to show that cosz is enitre ?

Comment: What do you mean by "image of" ?

Comment: for example if am true cos x is image not function

Comment: $\cos(it)-i\sin(it)=e^t$, is there a need to say more ?

Comment: so coz is image of cos for any complex variable z

Comment: many students and many people until now didn't know that cosz and sinz are unbounded ,so i'm interest to have a proof which  show that

Comment: @boon het , but there is a case where coz is real for some angles , it does means that non constant is not enough to proof the above claim

Comment: $\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$. Now let $z$ move along the positive imaginary axis.

Comment: sin(0)=0 , z=0+0i so it's real (according to ur formula) . constant in this case

Comment: @zeraouliarafik it's not real because $(0,0)\neq 0$

Comment: @zeraouliarafik it is **definitely** enough. Use Arthur's method to show $\cos, \sin$ are unbounded, if you need that

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of giving an explicit computation accessible to good high-school students:

If one accepts that
$$
\left.
\begin{gathered}
\exp(iz) = \cos z + i\sin z, \\
\exp(z + w) = \exp(z) \exp(w),
\end{gathered}\right\}\quad\text{for all complex $z$ and $w$,}
\tag{1}
$$
then unboundedness of both $\cos$ and $\sin$ along the imaginary axis follows from Yves Daoust's comment.

> More generally, the real and imaginary parts of the circular functions are given by:
>   $$
> \left.
> \begin{aligned}
> \cos(x + iy) &= \cos x \cosh y - i\sin x \sinh y, \\
> \sin(x + iy) &= \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y.
> \end{aligned}\right\}\quad\text{for all real $x$, $y$.}
> $$
>   Since the hyperbolic functions $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ are unbounded, $\cos$ and $\sin$ are also unbounded.

*Proof*: By Euler's formula,
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\exp(iz)  &= \cos z + i\sin z, \\
\exp(-iz) &= \cos z - i\sin z,
\end{aligned}\right\}\quad\text{for all complex $z$.}
\tag{2}
$$
Adding and subtracting, we find
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\cos z &= \frac{\exp(iz) + \exp(-iz)}{2}, \\
\sin z &= \frac{\exp(iz) - \exp(-iz)}{2i},
\end{aligned}\right\}\quad\quad\text{for all complex $z$.}
\tag{3}
$$

Setting $z = x + iy$ with $x$ and $y$ real in (3), so that $iz = ix - y$ and $-iz = -ix + y$, the law of exponents and Euler's formula give
\begin{align*}
\cos(x + iy) &= \tfrac{1}{2} \bigl[\exp(ix - y) + \exp(-ix + y)\bigr] \\
  &= \tfrac{1}{2}\bigl[e^{-y}(\cos x + i\sin x) + e^{y}(\cos x - i\sin x)\bigr] \\
  &= \cos x \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(e^{y} + e^{-y})\bigr] - i\sin x \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(e^{y} - e^{-y})\bigr] \\
  &= \cos x \cosh y - i\sin x \sinh y,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sin(x + iy) &= \tfrac{1}{2i} \bigl[\exp(ix - y) - \exp(-ix + y)] \\
  &= -\tfrac{i}{2} \bigl[e^{-y}(\cos x + i\sin x) - e^{y}(\cos x - i\sin x)\bigr] \\
  &= \sin x \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(e^{y} + e^{-y})\bigr] + i\cos x \bigl[\tfrac{1}{2}(e^{y} - e^{-y})\bigr] \\
  &= \sin x \cosh y + i\cos x \sinh y.
\end{align*}